# Convert matplotlib AxesImage to PIL PhotoImage, how to plot a matplotlib result in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to do the following:

1. Create plot with `imshow()` using matplotlib package, which gives `matplotlib.image.AxesImage`
2. Convert `matplotlib.image.AxesImage` to `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage`
3. Use this `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` as image on TkInter canvas

How can I accomplish the above without saving any image?

After referring a post I tried to directly color code my data with the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import numpy as np
from pylab import cm
root=Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)    
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
myarray = np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)
image1 = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.gist_earth(myarray)*255))
test = canvas.create_image(10,10,image = image1)
#canvas.itemconfig(test, image=nextimage)    
mainloop()
```

The above code gives the error

```
TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=120x100 at 0x2DC01E8>" doesn't exist
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: -Could you avoid step 2 and 3 and directly use fig in canvas Tkinter? see [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930143/matplotlib-plot-in-tkinter-every-update-adds-new-navigationtoolbar)

-Else you can redirect output from savefig into a buffer, see:[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869321/is-there-a-way-to-convert-pyplot-imshow-object-to-numpy-array)

Comment: @Katsu Please refer my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create and empty `ImageTk.PhotoImage` instance, and then paste the content from your `Image` instance there.

If you are reading from an `AxesImage` object (returned by `imshow`), you can transfer its data to `Image` first, then paste to `PhotoImage`.

Here is an example (note that you actually need to compute `myarray` over a meshgrid):

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
root=Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, copy=False)
myarray = np.cos(X) + np.cos(Y)

im_plt = plt.imshow(myarray)

image1 = Image.fromarray(np.uint8( im_plt.get_cmap()(im_plt.get_array())*255))
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage('RGB', image1.size)
im.paste(image1)
test = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=im)
mainloop()
```

Which will result in something like:

[image]

Comment: Can i paste matplotlib.image.AxesImage generated by imshow on this PhotoImage as well?

Comment: i can able to do that by using BytesIO like this `buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
buf.seek(0)
image11 = Image.open(buf)
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage('RGBA',(120,100))
im.paste(image11)` is there a way to paste directly??

Comment: @lokesh I've updated the answer... it is possible to pass directly the content from `imshow` to `Image`, then paste to `PhotoImage`

Comment: @lokesh I haven't played enough to tell you now... but I believe there is a shortcut in order to avoid this

Comment: the result is not matching. PhotoImage is different and imshow plot is different try to plot separately check the difference

Comment: where the difference is coming?