# two matplotlib figures in two different tk canvas

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter

I tried to adapt Hans' answer in [Matplotlib plot in Tkinter - every update adds new NavigationToolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930143/matplotlib-plot-in-tkinter-every-update-adds-new-navigationtoolbar) to have 2 different plots in 2 different canvas.

I have a problem: I don't know how to refer to the two different figures.

Although fig1 is in canvas1 and fig2 in canvas2, the plt.plot function doesnt refer to them - and plt.figure() doesnt help. How can I plot one thing in a canvas and a different thing in the other one?

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

def plotthem():
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.clf()
    x = np.arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
    y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x+random.random())
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.clf()
    x = np.arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
    y = np.tan(2*np.pi*x+random.random())
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()

root = Tk()

b = Button(root, text="Plot", command = plotthem)
b.grid(row=0, column=0)

# init figures
fig1 = plt.figure()

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=root)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas1, root)
canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=1)
toolbar.grid(row=1,column=1)

fig2 = plt.figure()
canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=root)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas2, root)
canvas2.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=2)
toolbar.grid(row=1,column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured it out...
You just have to use `plt.gcf().canvas.draw()` each time, since `gcf()` stands for *get current figure*, and working in tandem with `plt.figure(`) it is able to update different figures in different canvas.